# How can I use Fluent API in Entity Framework 6 to Map a List of One To Many objects without a foreign key property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-entity-framework

I have the following classes (that i'm not able to update, add properties or add annotations to):

```
public class ApprovalRuleset
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<ApprovalRule> ApprovalRules { get; protected internal set; }
}

public class ApprovalRule
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; protected internal set; }
}
```

I'm trying to write some Fluent API code with Entity Framework 6 to map these to two tables.

This is the ApprovalRule configuration:

```
public class ApprovalRuleEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApprovalRule>
{
    public ApprovalRuleEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(450);
    }
}
```

So far I've got:

```
public class ApprovalRulesetEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApprovalRuleset>
{
    public ApprovalRulesetEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasMany(x => x.ApprovalRules);
    }
}
```

> The Foreign Key on table 'ApprovalRules' with columns
>   'ApprovalRuleset_Id' could not be created because the principal key
>   columns could not be determined. Use the AddForeignKey fluent API to
>   fully specify the Foreign Key.

```
public class ApprovalRulesetEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApprovalRuleset>
{
    public ApprovalRulesetEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(x => x.ApprovalRules)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

> Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role
>   'ApprovalRuleset_ApprovalRules_Target' in relationship
>   'ApprovalRuleset_ApprovalRules'. Because all of the properties in the
>   Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role
>   must be '1'.

What am I missing?  I've spent ages searching stack overflow and google.

Comment: `HasMany(x => x.ApprovalRules)` is the correct configuration, although event without it by convention you should get what you want. Can you show the `ApprovalRule` configuration as well?

Comment: Turns out if I have a blank database it runs ok with HasMany(x => x.ApprovalRules)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add two properties in ApprovalRule class. Then mapping would be like this -

```
public class ApprovalRuleset
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<ApprovalRule> ApprovalRules { get; protected internal set; }
}

public class ApprovalRule
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; protected internal set; }

    public int ApprovalRulesetId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApprovalRuleset ApprovalRuleset { get; set; }
}

public class ApprovalRulesetEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApprovalRuleset>
{
    public ApprovalRulesetEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}

public class ApprovalRuleEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApprovalRule>
{
    public ApprovalRuleEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        /*Property(t => t.Value)
            .HasMaxLength(100);*/

        HasRequired(t => t.ApprovalRuleset)
            .WithMany(t => t.ApprovalRules)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ApprovalRulesetId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to update the Approval Rule or Ruleset class.  Do you have any other ideas how to do this?

Comment: If you do not have `ApprovalRulesetId` property inside `ApprovalRule` class, you cannot make a relationship between two classes in Entity Framework. There is no work around; you cannot even manually them like this - `from s in db.ApprovalRuleset join r in db.ApprovalRule on r.Id equals s.ApprovalRulesetId where s.Id == 1 select s`